# Show an image in my header.php

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, images, front-end, headers

I want to let my customer choose any image (in my backend) and then it will be displayed in my header.php. i've found Image Widget, but it just show images in the sidebar. I want something like:

```
<?php wp_plugin_that_shows_a_simple_image(); ?>
```

In my header.
Which plugin could I use? I've searched a lot.
WP 3.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress contains [built-in support to select header images for a theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers). You only have to indicate that your theme supports this, by calling [`add_custom_image_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header). See [the Twenty Ten initialization](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php#L114) for details.

In your theme's `header.php` you then call `header_image()` to get the current header image.

Comment: If i want to put this image in another file, does it still work? Thank you.

Comment: @thom: You mean putting the `header_image()` in another file than `header.php`? That is no problem. You can call it where you want.